# How can i load an image with pygame without defining the path

Tags: python, path, pygame

so i have this problem when i try to load an image with pygame without defining the path. I want it to get work. it would be important for getting it to work bc im making a game. could someone help me.

```
programIcon = pygame.image.load('ikon.png')
pygame.display.set_icon(programIcon)
```

this doesnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the image in the same directory as your script? The only way it can load the image without a path is if it's in the same directory.

Comment: both of them are in the same folder called game